# error: Table 'days.days' doesn't exist

Tags: php, html, sql

Having the above error message when trying to update a database field using HTML forms and PHP. Not sure whats wrong with my code (I know its unsafe, I'm just using it for personal use). I've checked and the database `days` does exist.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <form method="post" name="update" action="updateform.php" />
        Description:

        <input type="text"  name="description" />
        id:  
        <input type="text" name="id" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" Value="update" />
    </form>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "zoommooz") or die("Connection Failed"); 
    mysql_select_db("days")or die("Connection Failed"); 
    $description = $_POST['description']; 
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "UPDATE days 
                 SET description = '$description'
               WHERE id = '$id'";
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die("error: ".mysql_error());
    if(mysql_query($query)){ echo "updated";} else{ echo "fail";} ?>
```

**ERROR:**

```
error: Table 'days.days' doesn't exist
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:** the database is called days, the table is called hobby. I think that's what's wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it now.

Comment: Are you sure your table and/or database is named `days`? I bet your database is not named `days`.

Comment: or may be selecting a wrong DB ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your database name is `days` and your table name is `hobby` your code should be changed accordingly:

```
$query = "UPDATE days
```

to

```
$query = "UPDATE hobby
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how u can fix it, just put the correct table name in the query instead of db name.

```
$query = "UPDATE `hobby` 
SET description = '$description'
WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Comment: Thanks, im so dumb, cant believe i couldn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE hobby,
Not days.
You update the table mate.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is called `hobby` your `UPDATE` query should look like this

```
$query = "UPDATE hobby SET description = '$description' WHERE id = '$id'";
```